# How to enable persistence in Ubuntu's live CD (made with Unetbootin)?

Tags: live-usb, unetbootin, persistence

I have an 8gb USB that I used with Unetbootin to install Ubuntu 17.04 live CD. I enabled persistence during the installation but once I rebooted, everything was back to default. According to Gparted, the filesystem is FAT32 and the casper-rw file is in the root of the USB drive. How do I enable it to boot with persistence? or is something wrong?

Comment: Unetbootin *should* make it work without any extra action to activate persistence. You can check, that the boot option `persistent` is there, and add it if necessary. Otherwise you can use mkusb to make a persistent live drive. It uses grub to boot and a casper-rw **partition** instead of a file. See these links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent